# UWP Video SlowMotion and Reverse Effect

Tags: c#, video, uwp, slowmotion, video-effects

I am developing an UWP Desktop Application, where I would like to capture a video with my WebCam and apply some Video Effects on it.

I am using MediaComposition, MediaClip, MediaOverlay to composite multiple videos and intro pngs as a composition and put some overlays on it.
Now I was trying to implement a slow motion and reverse (boomerang /pingpong) video effect on my composition. I was expecting, that there are already some available IBasicVideoEffect effects for that, but I am searching since 3 days and not able to find something similar.

There is also FFmpegInteropX, which is I was trying but still not able to achieve my goal. But I also would like to avoid using FFMPEG in my project.

Does someone have any Ideas how to implement a slow motion and reverse video effect with UWP?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could use  [`SlowMotionEffectDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.effects.slowmotioneffectdefinition?view=winrt-15063)to make your video slow.